# How to form functions similar to $\frac 12 - \frac12 \cos \pi x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, curves

I wanted to know how to form curves similar to that of $y = \frac12 - \frac12\cos(\pi x)$. What I need is a function that forms a smooth curve been $x = 0$ to $x = 1$. As you see with the $y = \frac12 - \frac12\cos(\pi x)$ function, between $x = 0$ and $1$, the $y$ value smoothly goes from $y = 0$ to $y = 1$.

However I was wondering how I would go about augmenting this function such that the curve between $0$ and $1$ is more harsh (e.g. the curve goes from $y = 0$ to $y = 1$ jumps up more abruptly) or more gradual (e.g. the curve resembles something that looks like $y = x$)

Comment: How about $y=1-(1-x)^a$, for some choice of $a > 0$? For $a$ close to $1$ (e.g., $a=.9$ or $a=1.1$), the curve is close to $y=x$. Also look at other values of $a$, say $a=1/2$ or $a=2$ to get an idea of how the value of $a$ affects the shape of the curve.

Comment: You may enjoy the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, and in this case, a Taylor series at $0.5$ (or heck, even $0$ if you're willing to write out enough terms) would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...I was wondering how I would go about augmenting this function such that the curve between $0$ and $1$ is more harsh (e.g. the curve goes from $y = 0$ to $y = 1$ jumps up more abruptly) or more gradual (e.g. the curve resembles something that looks like $y = x$)

it seems to me that what you want is something like what computer graphics practitioners call a "bias" function.

The first version of this is due to [Ken Perlin](https://doi.org/10.1145/74334.74359), he of the award-winning noise function ubiquitous in CG. The definition he uses is

$$\mathtt{bias}(b,t) = t^{-\frac{\log b}{\log 2}}$$

Since transcendental functions are involved, the evaluation of this can get expensive; [Schlick](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~schlick/DOC/gem2.ps.gz) thus devised an alternative rational function that can be used for the same purpose:

$$\mathtt{bias}(b,t) = \frac{t}{(1/b-2)(1-t)+1}$$

In both instances, $b$ is an adjustable parameter. You can tweak it to get the desired manner of increase.

Comment: (I have no plotting software at the moment, so plots may have to wait until much later.)

Comment: smoothstep was exactly what i was lookong for

Answer (score 2):

The following function is a good choice to satisfy your requirement:

$$ y(x)=x^{t}(2-x)^{t}$$

You may vary the parameter $t$ to regulate steep or slow rise of the curve from 0 to 1.[image]

Comment: close, but I was looking for a function where fx(0) = 0 and fx(1) = 1, this function seems to have fx(0) = 0 and fx(1) = 0 when sliding (ive been sliding between t = [-10, 10] )

Comment: you may just shift 1 to 2

Comment: ahhh beautiful, would you know of any sigmoid shape curves from 0 to 1 that I can also have a slider for?

Comment: Try $\tanh [tx/(1-x)]$.

Comment: @Jozef, look up "smoothstep".